# ionic how to add blank page as home page of the app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I would like to add new page into default ionic app with tabbed menu and display this page as the default page of the app.

**Here is how I tried to do that:**
I added new state into app.js

```
.state('home', {
          url: '/home',
          views: {
              'home': {
                  templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                  controller: 'HomeCtrl'
              }
          }
    })
```

and set default router to home page

```
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

**And template file:**

```
<ion-view title="Home">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <h1>Home page</h1>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Now, if I am trying to go to `http://myapp.loc/index.html#/home` I got always black page without content.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:** 
In order to **Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'HomeCtrl' is not a function, got undefined**
I'm adding related code.

**Added controllers:**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $location) {

})
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {
})

.controller('FriendsCtrl', function($scope, Friends) {
  $scope.friends = Friends.all();
})

.controller('FriendDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Friends) {
  $scope.friend = Friends.get($stateParams.friendId);
});
```

**Order in index.html is following**

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/overall_stats.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need an abstract state that will hold your tabs, with a named view.

Comment: There is the abstract state called tab, but my view for home page does no contain any included tab bar or something. I would like to display simple page with header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say, that solution here should be surprisingly simple:

- Remove the view *name* `'home'`. In fact change it to `''` *(empty string)*

There is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dm52B9Z6n4teOF1e79Ym?p=preview) with this change?

```
.state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
          // instead of this
          // 'home': {

          // use this
          '': {
              templateUrl: 'tpl.home.html',
              controller: 'HomeCtrl',
          }
      }
})
```

Why? Because most likely the *index.html* would look like this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" >

    ...
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

</body>
```

And that means that the view name is "", almost like `<ion-nav-view name=""></ion-nav-view>`

Check that in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dm52B9Z6n4teOF1e79Ym?p=preview)

EXTEND based on the question extension

if we use *ionic-like* approach with separated file and module for controllers:

```
// inside of the index.html
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

// the controller.js
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
```

We must be sure, that our `app.js` does contain that module as well:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
   'ionic',
   'starter.controllers' // this is a MUST
])
```

Comment: Hello, it works on half, page is correctly displayed but console debugger is throwing following error:

Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'HomeCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

I checked my controllers and HomeCtrl is already defined there.

Comment: Where it throws error? in my plunker or in your local code? Because in my plunker it should be working as it is. The reason is: I do have this part of the code there: `.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $location) {})`. Do you have that as well? `HomeCtrl` is controller name declared in a state def - so it must be injected into our module as well

Comment: Thanks, problem was that i have another separated controller which contains angular.module('starter.controllers', []) too. So now it seems be OK, but i cannot use separated controllers in this time. Thanks very much!

Comment: Great to see that ;) enjoy amazing `ui-router`