# Ionic app showing blank page on device only – suspecting ui-router issue

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am building Hybrid mobile app (Cordova + Ionic + Angularjs + ui-router) with three pages:

```
    -menuContent 
        -InProgTickets.html (landing page)
            -details
        -CompletedTickets.html
            -detailsCompleted
        -Setting
```

Notice that I am using the default side menu templates provided by Ionic. Here is the complete routing code:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider

  .state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.setting', {
      url: "/setting",
      views: {
          'menuContent': {
              templateUrl: "templates/setting.html",
              controller: "SettingsCtlr"
          }
      }
  })

  .state('app.InProgTickets', {
      url: "/InProgTickets",
      views: {
          'menuContent': {
              templateUrl: "templates/InProgTickets.html",
              controller: "InProgTicketsCtrl"
          }
      }
  })


.state('app.details', {
    url: "/details/:id",         
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/details.html",
            controller: "InProgTicketsCtrl"
        }
    }        
})
  .state('app.CompletedTickets', {
      url: "/CompletedTickets",
      views: {
          'menuContent': {
              templateUrl: "templates/CompletedTickets.html",
              controller: "CompletedCtrl"
          }
      }
  })
   .state('app.detailsCompleted', {
       url: "/detailsCompleted/:id",
       views: {
           'menuContent': {
               templateUrl: "templates/detailsCompleted.html",
               controller: "CompletedCtrl"
           }
       }
   });
// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/InProgTickets');})
```

My issue is that the app works just as expected in the ripple chrome simulator but it shows a white blank screen on android mobile device. I can’t find any issue with my ui-routing code and I have been playing around with few scenarios without any success, but I saw a related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826427/ionic-how-to-add-blank-page-as-home-page-of-the-app), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106830/ionic-stateprovider-showing-blank-page-on-device) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371779/ionic-routing-issue-shows-blank-page-in-link).

Comment: could you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28932268/2435473

Comment: none of the mentioned solutions worked for me. I tired to disable caching and changed the version number but nothing seems to work.

Comment: while creating an `href` attribute are you using `ui-sref` directive or you are creating manually using `ng-href="{{someUrl}}"`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/InProgTickets');})
```

should work in my opinion as '/InProgTickets' is actually the url of your state